# Find one vector in $\mathbb R^3$ which generates the intersection of V and W.

Tags: vector-spaces

Find one vector in $\mathbb R^3$ which generates the intersection of the planes $V$ and $W$, where $V$ is the $XY$-plane and $W$ is the space generated by the vectors $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,-1, 1)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What methods do you have in mind? Should we use row-reduction? Cross-products?

Answer (score 1):

Since the XY-plane has equation z=0 and every vector of W is of the type 
(a+b,2a-b,3a+b) a vector in both V and W has 3a+b=0 or b=-3a. Hence it has form 
(-2a,5a,0). It is easy to see that the intersection is generated by (-2,5,0).

Answer (score 0):

The space generated by the two vectors $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,-1,1)$ is a plane going through the origin and having the following normal vector

$$\vec n=(1,2,3)\times (1,-1,1)=(5,2,-3).$$

So, the equation of the of $W$ is

$$5x+2y-3z=0.$$

The equation of $V$, the $xy$-plane is

$$z=0.$$

Combining the equations above we get that the intersection of $V$ and $W$ is a straight line in the $xy$-plane whose equation is

$$2y=-5x \text{ or } y=-\frac52x.$$

Any vector lying on this straight line would generate it. Let $x=1$ then $y=-\frac53$ then

a suitable vector is

$$\left(1,-\frac52,0\right).$$

Comment: $y = - \frac{5}{2}x$!